# how can i put dashed lines around the -E boxplots, change the background of the graph and leave out the observation number from the boxplots?

Tags: r, graph, line, boxplot

```
graphxx<-ggplot(summer.months, aes(x=month, y=Temp_mean, color=canopy, fill=position)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle(" Temperature changes in elevated and lying deadwood in summer under different canopies") +
  labs(y= "temperature values", x = "months")+
  lines(position,"-E",type ="1")+
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun = median,position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
graphxx+scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "white","green", "black"))
```

I tried to put dashed lines around the E boxplots, change the background and delete the number of observations from the boxplots but I´m a beginner here so i don´t really know how to do all those things

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: should i send my boxplots as well? cuz i thought i explained what i tried to do

Comment: Without any data we can't run your code so it's hard to know what you are looking at or what you want to change exactly.

Comment: how can i send my r script and my data on this page?